# How to round a scientific number to n digits while keeping the scientific property?

Tags: r, rounding

How would I round a scientific number to n digits? But still keep the E...

Desired Output:

```
round(num,2) ## Just an example, I know this does not work.
1.78943642E-10 -> 1.79E-10
2.68289674E-11 -> 2.68E-11
6.23486821E-15 -> 6.23E-15
```

Comment: `signif(c(1.78943642e-10, 2.68289674e-11, 6.23486821e-15), 3)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for `signif()` (round to a specified number of significant digits)?

Eg:

```
x <- 1e18/pi; x
# 3.183099e+17
signif(x, 2)
# 3.2e+17
```

---

If you are looking to 'force' printing of scientific notation, maybe as part of a label on a plot, you can use `formatC()`

```
formatC(0.01235, format="e", digits=2)
# "1.23e-02"
```

The output here is character, so you can't do mathematical operations (directly) on it.